# Can't connect to MySQL server from my webserver, works fine using the exact same file on my personal box

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a godaddy server where I need site users to be able to enter in tracking numbers to see if we have it in the system. I coded it in php/pdo, and it works just fine hosted on my personal machine no matter where it is located (local or remote). I upload the exact same php file to the godaddy server, and all I get is a timeout and a mysql error saying that it can't connect.

Comment: You really haven't provided much information for people to help.  Is the MySQL server expected to be local to the application or on a remote server? Do you have use accounts configured appropriately for MySQL server for host you are calling from? What is the full MySQL information that you are receiving?

Comment: The mysql server, web server, and my personal machine are three separate machines on completely different IPs right now. It works on my personal machine, but not on the hosted webserver. The username@hostname is set to 'username'@'%'. I get the following error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '50.75.216.26' (110)

Comment: What happens if you try to ping the 50.75.216.26 machine from the GoDaddy server or mysql command line from there?

Comment: I only have ftp access from the GoDaddy server.

Comment: hit up godaddy support. They have articles on this, and if those don't cover it, file a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

change your connection string ip address to localhost . It means your get infomation from the hosting server with this password and username. The username and password and database is your own ofcourse. 1 Question what program are you using to upload the file to the hosting server?

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","my_db") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The MySQL server is on a different machine on a different ip from the web server. Changing it to "localhost" won't fix it because it's not on Localhost. I'm also using PDO and not MySQLi, but that's not a big deal.

Comment: I had the same problem but my server is on the same machine as the hosting server. So thats why the localhost works for me. But have you tried it yet?? you may never know. Btw if the problem is with your connection please paste the connection code in your question so more people can understand

Comment: JUst try it and see how it works. Use Filezilla and try not to use mysql as it will be removed in the future.